# "Error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR"

Tags: c#, multithreading, clr

let me start by explaining my program and what is happening.
My program use a GSM Modem to read messages from a mobile card and then it shows the messages in a Marquee...
This error is really random, I have tested this program in a disco of a friend and sometimes it work all night without crashing and other days it crash over and over...
So, there is the code of the class that does the Marquee (and it's where it crashes):

```
public class MyPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{

    private LinkedList<string> texto;
    private LinkedList<MensagemParaEcra> msgs;
    private LinkedList<Label> labels;
    private LinkedList<string> msgsRemover = new LinkedList<string>();
    private List<Label> labelsRmv = new List<Label>();
    private List<Label> labelARemover = new List<Label>();
    private Label firstLb;
    private Label lastLb;
    private Label leftLb;
    private Label lastLb3;

    private Color color;
    private Color backg;
    private Font textFont;
    private Label lastLb2;
    private Screen screen;

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public MyPanel(Color corLabel, Color back, Font text)
    {
        this.color = corLabel;
        this.backg = back;
        this.textFont = text;
        this.Width = 4000;

        texto = new LinkedList<string>();
        msgs = new LinkedList<MensagemParaEcra>();
        labels = new LinkedList<Label>();

        MouseMove += MyPanel_MouseMove;

        this.BackColor = backg;
        this.Size = new Size(4000, 69);
        this.Refresh();
        Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
        screen = Screen.FromControl(BarraSms.getInstance());
    }

    public void addMensagem(MensagemParaEcra msg) // add a message to be displayed in the monitor
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = (msg.getTexto() + " -");
        lbl.ForeColor = color;
        lbl.Font = textFont;
        lbl.BackColor = backg;
        lbl.Visible = true;
        lbl.AutoSize = true;

        if (labels.Count > 0)
        {
            lbl.Location = new Point(this.lastLb3.Right, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.Location = new Point(screen.Bounds.Width + 10, 0);
            firstLb = lbl;
        }

        reorderAdd(lastLb3, lbl);
        labels.AddLast(lbl);

        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        this.Refresh();
        this.lastLb3 = lbl;
    }

    private void reorderAdd(Label ultima, Label lbl) //reorder the list order when the user add a new message
    {
        var it = labels.OrderBy(x => x.Location.X);

        int count;
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
        {
            if (it.ElementAt(i) == ultima)
            {
                count = i;
                lbl.Location = new Point(ultima.Right, 0);
                try
                {
                    if (it.ElementAt(i + 1) != null)
                        it.ElementAt(i + 1).Location = new Point(lbl.Right, 0);
                }catch{
                }
                for (int a = count+2; a < labels.Count; a++)
                {
                    if(it.ElementAt(a) != null)
                    it.ElementAt(a).Location = new Point(it.ElementAt(a-1).Right, 0);
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }


    public void startT()
    {
        startThread();
    }

    public void removerMsg(string msg) //remove the message
    {
        string remover = msg + " -";  

        Label lb = getMsg(remover);

        labels.Remove(lb);
        this.Controls.Remove(lb); 
        this.Refresh();
        if(labels.Count >1)
        reorder();
    }

    private Label getMsg(string msg) //method to find a message in the list
    {
        var node = labels.First;
        while (node != null)
        {            
            var nextNode = node.Next;
            if (node.Value.Text.Equals(msg))
            {
                return node.Value;
            }
            node = nextNode;

        }
        return null;
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    public void setVelocidade(int ve) { //used to set the interval of the timmer
        myTimer.Interval = ve;
    }
    private void startThread()
    {

        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timerEvent);
        myTimer.Interval = 20;
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    private void MyPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) //used to move the unborded window
    {
        BarraSms.getInstance().mouseMove(e);
    }

    [System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute()] //I found this when I was searching for the error but it didn't help me
    private void timerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           var it4 = labels.OrderBy(x => x.Location.X);
           // var it = it4.GetEnumerator();

            //while (it.MoveNext())
            foreach(Label lb in it4)
            {
              //  Label lb = it.Current; //sometimes it crashes here

                if (firstLb == null)
                    firstLb = lb;

                if (lb.Location.X + lb.Width < 0) {
                    lb.Location = new Point(it4.Last().Right, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    lb.Location = new Point(lb.Location.X - 4, lb.Location.Y);
                    leftLb = lb;
                }

                lastLb = lb;
            }
            this.Refresh(); //other times it crashes here
            if(labels.Count >2 )
            reorder();
    }

    private void reorder() { //used to reorder my list by the location on the screen
        var it2 = labels.OrderBy(x => x.Location.X);
        Label orderLb = it2.ElementAt(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < labels.Count; i++)
        {
            it2.ElementAt(i).Location = new Point(orderLb.Right, 0);
            orderLb = it2.ElementAt(i);
        }
    }

    public void applyDestaque(string msg) { //its just to highlight a message
        Label lb = getMsg(msg + " -");
        labels.Find(lb).Value.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        labels.Find(lb).Value.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    public void removeDestaque(string msg) { // remove the highlight
        Label lb = getMsg(msg + " -");
        labels.Find(lb).Value.BackColor = backg;
        labels.Find(lb).Value.ForeColor = color;
    }

    internal void addMensagemDestaque(MensagemParaEcra mensagemParaEcra)  // add a highlighted message
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = (mensagemParaEcra.getTexto() + " -");
        lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        lbl.Font = textFont;
        lbl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        lbl.Visible = true;
        lbl.AutoSize = true;

        if (labels.Count > 0)
        {
            lbl.Location = new Point(this.lastLb3.Right, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            lbl.Location = new Point(screen.Bounds.Width + 10, 0);
            firstLb = lbl;
        }

        reorderAdd(lastLb3, lbl);
        labels.AddLast(lbl);
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        this.Refresh();
        this.lastLb3 = lbl; 
    }
}
```

Well, that's all...

I have searching over and over but I wasn't able to fix it or find any solution...
Edit: The changes I made so  far was updated in my code, I comment the lines that I had inside the thread and added the foreach cicle that you told me to do

This is the full error:

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x5f44a62c, on thread 0x2040. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the  CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug  include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

Edit: added a bounty for who can help me with this bug...

Comment: Instead if iterating over the enumerable manually.. why not remove the `while` loop and replace it with a `foreach`? That will eliminate your potential to access the wrong element. Also, the Timer control has a rough accuracy of 55 milliseconds. You've set it to 20.. so it's not going to be as quick as you think it will.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed that, now I will let it run in my computer for some hours and in this weekend I will put it in my friend disco for see if it still crash or not... Thank you a lot!

Comment: Can you try this also: in the timer's `Tick` event.. disable the timer at the top of the event and re-enable it at the bottom? Just to make sure that the re-entrant nature of it isn't causing you issues? It would also be good if you updated your question with the new code so we could see it (and make sure its what is expected).

Comment: That's a fair amount of code for us to read. Can you narrow down the problem at all? And, where, exactly do you get the error, and please post the full exception (ex.ToString()).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I posted the new code, tomorrow night I will test it in another computer all night and see if it still crashing with the foreach or no. At sunday I will update my question with the answer... But can you tell me what you mean in the timer's tick event?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I posted the full error, well... the crash is kinda random, but it happens in the "timerEvent" method, sometimes was on the while, others on the this.Refresh(), so I'm not really sure what is making the crashes... maybe was the while, so now I have a foreach cicle and I will test it tomorrow, then I will keep you updated. Thank you for the help

Comment: In the `timerEvent` function.. disable the timer at the start of the function then enable it at the end. This is to test whether the re-entrant nature of the tick event is causing the issues with your iteration.

Comment: I just arrive home now to tell you that I have tested the new code tonight and it still crashing... I guess it might be something about the access on the list, but I'm not sure... I should lock the access of my messages lists for the thread doesn't crash the program?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Wouldn't the fact that OP is using [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) (as opposed to [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) make it single-threaded (per documentation) and thus non-reentrant?

Comment: @JoãoSilva Where are you seeing that error message? I don't see any `try/catch` in your code. If it is at some other place, do you know the type of the exception you're getting - this may help diagnose.

Comment: It seems from it's documentation that the attribute you're using need a [SecurityCritical] in order to work. From the documentation: `The CLR delivers the corrupted process state exception to applicable exception clauses only in methods that have both the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute and SecurityCriticalAttribute attributes`. What you could try is to add the [SecurityCritical] attribute and catch any exception in the method to log them and see if it gives you some more info (but I kinda doubt it, Isay this because I had already a bad experience with access violation)

Comment: Another thing you could try is to set the debug mode to native. When the exception happen it should let you see either the decompiled code or the source if the crash is happening in a Windows (i.e. not third party) library and you have the symbol file for that library (for that you may try to activate the download symbols from the microsoft server in the settings of visual studio)

Comment: @LB2 That appear when it crashed while im running it using visual studio...

Comment: @FabioMarcolini can you post a link of that documentation for I see the exact attribute? and about that debbug mode, I already tried that but there is no option on this visual studio and I dont know why... I have search how can I activate and I couldn't found it...

Comment: @JoãoSilva Do you have any PInvoke code (that would be even remotely related to the code where it crashes)?

Comment: @JoãoSilva here is the [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute.aspx) documentation you can see the bit I wrote in the Remarks.

Comment: Try adding the following lines when removing Label from the Controls.  `lb.Dispose();  lb = null;`  There could be a problem with the resources not being released as messages are processed.

Comment: Do you use any third-party libraries (such as to interface with the GSM modem)? A bug in some unmanaged code could cause this error.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, yes I do and there is people using it and it works fine...

Comment: @bytedreamer, ok... I will add it but since i added the securitycritical attribute, the program seams to not crash but once stop responding... I will do more tests on it

Comment: @FabioMarcolini can you post an answer with the attribute so I can award the bounty?

Comment: @JoãoSilva Yay, my first bounty :)

Comment: @JoãoSilva Can you say what the libraries are and how they're used? Issues like this are often environment-dependent so some other people using them successfully doesn't prove that they're bug-free.

Comment: I used a library from this project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem 
I took the connection between the computer and the modem and then developed the program following my needs

Answer (score 0):

It seems from it's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that the attribute you're using need a [[SecurityCritical]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to work. From the documentation:

`The CLR delivers the corrupted process state exception to applicable exception clauses only in methods that have both the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute and SecurityCriticalAttribute attributes`.

What you could try is to add the [[SecurityCritical]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute and catch any exception in the method to log them and see if it gives you some more infos.

Comment: It's not clear how this will help solve the problem. Putting the two attributes on a function will allow the function to catch the exception, but what will that accomplish? Attempting to continue after such an exception is not likely to have a positive outcome. As far as debugging, it doesn't seem necessary since the exception is already being raised and catchable by the debugger.